# Not able to send email to Distribution List

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, smtpclient

Requirement is quite basic, sending an email to an Exchange distribution list.

Code is:

```
    public void SendMessage(
        string from, string to, string cc, string bcc, string subject)
    {
        string hostName = "localhost";
        var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(from); 
        message.CC.Add(cc);
        message.To.Add(to); //to is the email address of distribution list
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Bcc.Add(bcc);

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(hostName);
        smtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _loggingService.LogException(e, _applicationContextService.CurrentUsername);
        }
    }
```

Here "to" is the email address of distribution list.

Program delivers email to CC and BCC but it fails to deliver email to members of the distribution list. I have disabled "require that all senders are authenticated" for the distribution list that was explained at https://serverfault.com/a/24805. But still emails are not delivered to distribution list.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to include in `to` list only one address? How you form `to` list?

Comment: to is a string that represents the email address of DL. For example, it can be MyApp-GroupA@mydomain.com